# I am geting httpexception error with embed with a discored bot in python.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i am geting an httpexception error with embeds in discord.py with a bot i am making, i am new to this bot stuff so i dont get what the problem is. pls help

```
import discord
import os
import time
import discord.ext
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  ping_ms = round(client.latency * 1000)

  if ping_ms <= 50:
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f":green_circle: `{ping_ms} ms`", color=0x00FF00)
  elif ping_ms <= 100:
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f":yellow_circle: `{ping_ms} ms`", color=0xFFFF00)
  elif ping_ms <= 200:
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f":orange_circle: `{ping_ms} ms`", color=0xFFA500)
  else:
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f":red_circle: `{ping_ms} ms`", color=0xFF0000)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@client.command() 
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member):
  try:
    await member.kick(reason=None)
    await ctx.send("kicked "+member.mention)
  except:
    await ctx.send("bot does not have the kick members permission!")

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description='Test done', color=0x00ff00))

@client.command()
async def clear (ctx, number):
  num = int(number)
  await ctx.message.channel.purge(limit=num)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name='!help'))
  print(f"{client.user} is online")

msg_num = 0
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global msg_num
  msg_num += 1
  print(msg_num)
  if msg_num >= 100:
    await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(discription = '`Chats count has reached a 100, clearing chat...`',color=0xff0000))

 time.sleep(5)

 await message.channel.purge(limit=101)
 msg_num = 0

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

this is the image:
[this is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDMNK.png)

NOTE:

1. in the code above the embed in def ping works but not in the on_message.
2. the commands stop working if the @client.event on_message function is there in the code, and i dont know why.

Comment: Could you post your whole code, and the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `discription` instead of `description`:

```py
                                                 # here
await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(discription = '`Chats count has reached a 100, clearing chat...`', color=0xff0000))
```

Then for the second question, your commands won't be processed because you overwritten `on_message` and didn't include [`client.process_commands(message)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_command#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  await client.process_commands(message)

  global msg_num
  msg_num += 1

  if msg_num >= 100:
    await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description = '`Chats count has reached a 100, clearing chat...`',color=0xff0000))

    time.sleep(5)

    await message.channel.purge(limit=101)
    msg_num = 0
```

Also, you shouldn't use `time.sleep`, since it will block your entire code when it's executed. You should use `asyncio.sleep`:

```py
import asyncio

...

await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, and can you explane what does the await client.process_commands(message)
 do